# .Net Core 3.1 and Postgresql Insert and Update Query is not executing but Select query is running successfully

Tags: postgresql, api, asp.net-core

Hello Everyone I am using Postgresql with .Net Core Api 3.1 without entity framework when i am requesting to postgresql for running any function which is inserting data and select data in refcursor.

In this function select query is running perfectly but data is not inserting in database table.

The same function working properly in Asp .Net Web Forms but not in Asp .Net Core.

I am new on postgresql

```cs
public string Save_Siteinpection_update(SiteInspection model)
{
    string result = ResponseStatus.FAILED;
    try
    {
        var conn = SqlHelper.NpSqlConnection();
        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        var tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
        var command1 = new NpgsqlCommand("mob_sp_siteinspection_update3", conn);

        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_document_sno", Convert.ToInt64(model.docsrno));
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_dig_code", Convert.ToInt32(model.dig_code));
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_srocode", Convert.ToInt32(model.srocode));
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_site_visited", model.site_visited);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_visit_satisfy", model.visit_satisfy);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_contact_person", model.contact_person);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_longitude_prop", model.longitude_prop);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_latitude_prop", model.latitude_prop);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_adrees_prop", model.adrees_prop);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_city_prop", model.city_prop);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_zip", model.zip);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_country_prop", model.country_prop);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_state_prop", model.state_prop);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_img1", model.img1);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_img2", model.img2);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_img3", model.img3);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_img4", model.img4);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("para_remark", model.remark);
        command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command1);
        da.Fill(ds);

        string np_no = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["mob_sp_siteinspection_update3"].ToString();

        command1.CommandText = "fetch all in \"" + np_no + "\"";
        command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        NpgsqlDataReader sdr = command1.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            result = Convert.ToString(sdr[0].ToString());
        }
        sdr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Where do you insert data? Had expected some INSERT statement and and execute on the command object.

Comment: Is there has some error message when Insert and update the records? According to your code, you are using a stored procedure to update the entity, could you post the related stored procedure statement?